# Escape closing Tag in embedded JavaScript on a JSF page

Tags: javascript, jsf, jquery-select2

I've got a following JS function that formats my results used in select2

```
function format(item) {
    if (item.text.match(/\[\d{4}\]/g)) {
        return "<b>" + item.text + "</b>";
    }
    return item.text;
}
```

If I leave it as it is I am getting following error in the JS console:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
return "<b>" + item.text + "
```

If I escape the slash like so `<\\/b>` then javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException complaints about not well-formatted code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just write JS code in a normal JS file. XHTML file is for XHTML code. JS code is not XHTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh, i see then it is jsf special charachter parsing issue. `'<'` is `"&lt;"` and `'>'` is `"&gt;"`.

Replace these characters like:

```
return "&lt;b&gt;" + item.text + "&lt;/b&gt;";
```

This will work for you.

Comment: thanks Parkash Kumar for your effort, It would have worked. I decided to move all the JS to an external file once it worked anyway. Just wanted to see if it's doable in XHTML. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Welcome, well its also better to include JavaScript / CSS code from external file(s) for code readability and fluidity.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with it by exporting format function to an external JavaScript file and using this neat trick:

```
return "<b>" + item.text + "<" + "/b>";
```

Comment: You could have done it like: var retrunStr = "<b>" + item.text + "</b>"; return retrunStr;

Comment: actually if I move to an external file it goes even without the middle step, like so: `return "<b>" + item.text + "</b>";`